# python shapely plot multiple layers

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, shapely, ogr

There is a set of (lat, long) points which can be simply visualized by `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(list_of_longitudes, list_of_latitudes)`. But I want to plot these points on top of a road network which happens to be in a shapefile. How can I simply plot the two files together with Python in one single map/figure?

Especially looking for something like Shapely

Comment: Have a look at `cartopy` or `basemap`.  However, you'll also need to be aware of what projection your shapefile is in and possibly reproject the road network to match the coordinate system you're making the map in.